# The two images, one on the other in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, class

I'm trying to display couple of images on the other image.
It's important for me to have this pictures in two diffrent classes becous i need to connect this images with the other properties.
I wrote a class which add and display one picture at a time.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Obrazek {
     BufferedImage image;
     Obrazek(){
    File imageFile = new File("tło.jpg");
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Blad odczytu obrazka");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
    JPanel pane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };

}
```

Let say i have two classes of that kind, each with diffrent image.
Then I wrote my main class with main method which define frame and create image.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ButtonDemo{


        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            JFrame frame = buildFrame();
           Obrazek obraz = new Obrazek();


            frame.add(obraz.pane);
        }
        private static JFrame buildFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }

}
```

But when i add next frame.add(someobject.pane); it's delete previous one and displays only the last one. How to make them display together but from two separate classes.

Comment: Blad odczytu obrazka = Error reading image (polish)

Comment: The exact approach depends on the content and goal. Are you relying on transparency or geometry to compose the two images? Please clarify.

Comment: I have some image in background and i want to generate some pictures on this image, but this pictures, are going to generete at random moment and some of them are going to be generated by button.

Comment: @Vekka are u using any ide.? and ya when u trying to make image on image u need to set order for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "It's important for me to have this pictures in two diffrent classes becous i need to connect this images with the other properties"

You may be going about this incorrectly, trying to make each of these classes a `JPanel`. I mean, technically you could make it happen with a `JLayeredPane`. But I would go about it differently.

First to handle your *"other properties"*, you could use an `interface` to combine the objects you want to draw. Just have a define `draw` method in the interface.

```
public interface Drawable {
    void draw(Graphics g);
}
```

Then you can have a main panel to do the drawing. This panel will hold a `List` or `Map` of `Drawable` objects; a `List` if access after adding them is not important, and a `Map` if you need easy access to them after you add. For instance.

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    List<Drawable> drawList;
    // Map<String, Drawable> drawMap;

    public void addToDrawList(Drawable drawable) { 
        drawList.add(drawable);
        repaint();
    }

    // public void addToDrawMap(String key, Drawable drawable) {
    //     drawMap.put(key, drawable);
    //     repaint();
    // }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(Drawable drawable : drawList){
            drawable.draw(g);
        }

        // for (Drawable drawable : drawMap.values()) {
        //     drawable.draw(g);
        // }
    }
}
```

Now you can just make any class you want `implements Drawable`, and just add an instance of that class to the `drawList` or `drawMap`. This way everything is all drawn onto the same surface. For example

```
class HelloDrawable implements Drawable {
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello", 100, 100);
    }
}
class WorldDrawable implements Drawable {
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("World", 150, 100);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();
        panel.addToDrawList(new HelloDrawable());
        panel.addToDrawList(new WorldDrawable());

        // panel.addToDrawMap("Hello", new HelloDrawable());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In JavaFx You could use StackPane and ImageView
Put all images in ImageView and leter use stack Pane to put new image over the old one.